# What do I need to do to unlock the “Record Breaker” recipe?

Tags: fiz

According to [this link](https://fiz.gamepedia.com/Recipe) there is a Fiz recipe called “Record Breaker”.

What am I expected to do to earn this recipe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recipe is similar to Grubb’s Lite, placing the four ingredients in the same locations as their equivalents in that recipe (the locations are randomised on each play through).

The four ingredients in Record Breaker are:

- Lager Yeast
- Water
- Two-Row Malt
- Perle Hops

Comparison of Grubbs Lite arrangement vs Record Breaker:
[image: Grubb’s Lite]

[image: Record Breaker]

I still haven’t seen any in-game indication it exists, though, aside from the fact that you otherwise can’t obtain the “collected all recipes” achievement.

Answer (score 2):

To unlock the Record Breaker recipe, complete the event "It's a Sports Drink Too!" After the event, the marathon runner gives you the recipe because he wants something without alcohol next time.

To unlock this event (as with all events), keep playing after you have finished the Career, waiting for Z to sell the Essence of Goings On for 9,999 coins each. (You may also get the event out of luck, but completing certain events is required to unlock all recipes, characters and costumes).